# How to create an API for modules?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an C# application which receive and send message through an TCP socket. I made a C# library (dll) which contains interfaces so someone who would like to send information through that socket doesn't actually have to write the whole TCP part compile the application, etc.

They just use the functions that are provided in the library.

My question is: How would I implement an function in the library that would actually send the message (string, byte[], doesn't matter) through the already existing application?

The library actually contain a function for message received so :

---> raw data ---> application ---> library ---> dll implementing library's interfaces

Now I need to do the other part :

send data <--- application <--- library <--- dll implementing library's interfaces

```
namespace MyCustomAPI
{
    public interface I_Networking
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Triggered when a message is received through the TCP socket
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The message received through the TCP socket</param>
        void HandleMessage(string message);


        /// TODO: Implement send message function
    }
}
```

Am I thinking this all wrong?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. You have wrote an application, which receive data and you wrote a library which handle the communication, data format, etc. When the same library should be used by an other application to send data to your application, implement a send method, which could be called by the other application.

Comment: Well, yeah, but the thing is, I have no idea how. I tried passing the send function as a parameter to the library, but that doesn't seems clean to me.

I'd like the external user to be able to call a function in the library that would send the message, I have no idea how.

Comment: Then you should tell us a bit more, how your library works. I would expect a method like `void SendMessage(string message) { /* Send message to TCP socket */ }` in your library and the sending application would call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to implement a "send message" function in your dll, but this function also needs to do something with the application.
If that's the case, then I suggest you should provide an interface in your library where all the parameters needed for the "send message" function to be able to work independently are included, and return an object or something if necessary.

```
namespace MyCustomAPI
{
    public interface I_Networking
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Triggered when a message is received through the TCP socket
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The message received through the TCP socket</param>
        void HandleMessage(string message);


        /// TODO: Implement send message function
        object SendMessage(object param1, object param2);
    }
}
```

This is the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) approach. The dll should only be concerned with what it should be doing, not the other part trying to use it.